# setsavepassword in Android webview no longer supported on which version?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to know on which Android version, setSavePassword default value set as true and it has been no longer supported?

In documentation, I can find This method was deprecated in API level 18. But it has not been specified, which API level, it will no longer been supported.
Further it has been specified that,

Sets whether the WebView should save passwords. The default is true.

Let me know on which Android API level, this method has no longer been supported?